# ASP.NET Core MVC MySQL Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using 3rd party MySQL EntityFrameworkCore Extension

"SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "7.1.7"

Everything works but now I decided to use AspNetCore Identity Framework so I changed my DbContext to IdentityDbContext:

```
public class TwitchCharDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    public TwitchCharDbContext (DbContextOptions<TwitchCharDbContext> options) 
        : base(options)
    { }
}
```

When I run command to update database:

```
dotnet ef migrations add init
dotnet ef database update
```

I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Property'
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapperExtensions.GetMapping(IRelationalTypeMapper typeMapper, IProperty property)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.GetColumnType(String schema, String table, String name, Type clrType, Nullable`1 unicode, Nullable`1 maxLength, Boolean rowVersion, IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.ColumnDefinition(String schema, String table, String name, Type clrType, String type, Nullable`1 unicode, Nullable`1 maxLength, Boolean rowVersion, Boolean nullable, Object defaultValue, String defaultValueSql, String computedColumnSql, IAnnotatable annotatable, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at MySQL.Data.Entity.Migrations.MySQLMigrationsSqlGenerator.ColumnDefinition(String schema, String table, String name, Type clrType, String type, Nullable`1 unicode, Nullable`1 maxLength, Boolean rowVersion, Boolean nullable, Object defaultValue, String defaultValueSql, String computedColumnSql, IAnnotatable annotatable, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.ColumnDefinition(AddColumnOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateTableOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.DatabaseUpdateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Property'
```

Important note is that if I change destination database to MS SQL in Startup.cs it works as expected.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/auth/sign-in");
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<TwitchCharDbContext, int>();

services.AddDbContext<TwitchCharDbContext>(opt => {
                //opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TwitchChar"));
                opt.UseMySQL(
                    connectionString
                );
            });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a limitation in this specific MySQL connector that has been resolved in 7.1.9

You can report similar issues [here](https://github.com/SapientGuardian/SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql).

Comment: Perfect! It solved the problem I tried to update but nuget proposed me highest version of 7.1.7. I put 7.1.9 anyway and restored project successfully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This project seems to have a more complete implemention of migrations:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql